# If I am blending parsley for soup, can I use the parsley whole or should I still remove the stems?

Tags: soup, parsley

I am making my Grandma's parsley soup - it's chicken stock, onions, potatoes, garlic and parsley. Since the whole combination is blended, can I use the parsley stems or might not removing them have an adverse affect on taste?

Comment: Yes, it's good to use it, also in raw sauces it's good :-))

Comment: Just be sure to blend enough chunky texture, also good to roughly chop a few times for easier blending.

Comment: Grab a stalk, taste it. Decide 

Comment: One (probably unrelated) sidenote: My grandma told me that adding parsley during the cooking process might increase the risk of the soup turning sour, so be sure to cool it quickly (lid off, fridge etc.) when storing to prevent that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a lot of flavor in parsley stems, as is true of most "soft" herbs.  In my kitchen, if it is soft/palatable, I use it.

Comment: Is it the same flavor, or will you taste the difference? Is "use less but with stems" an alternative option, or is it not going to work?

Comment: I don't differentiate, unless it is for presentation or garnish, then I use leaves mainly...but finely chopped stems can be fine as well.  I don't notice a flavor difference, but there is more mass there, so...more parsley, for example...but, perceptibly different...I don't know...don't think it matters much.

Comment: It's pretty much the same except for texture. You might want to avoid stems for garnish (so you don't get "chunks"), but if you're blending/cooking it wont matter much, if at all.

Comment: To add to this: there's also parsley root, which you could consider the ultimate stem, which is also very tasty and very parsley-y (though with a hint of root vegetable as well)

Answer (score 1):

Put them in some cheesecloth and remove them at the end of cooking.

Comment: But the soup is blended?

Comment: Presumably remove before blending but after cooking